# How to config the marathon-lb when the container run in HOST network?

Tags: mysql, docker, marathon

My json for marathon is below

```
{
  "id": "/storage/mysql",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 512,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 1,
  "constraints": [
    [
      "hostname",
      "UNIQUE"
    ]
  ],
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": [],
    "docker": {
      "image": "reg.xxxxx.cn/library/mysql:5.7",
      "network": "HOST",
      "portMappings": [],
      "privileged": true,
      "parameters": [],
      "forcePullImage": false
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD": "123456"
  },
  "labels": {
    "HAPROXY_GROUP": "internal"
  },
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "port": 3306,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "labels": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I find the haproxy (run at 192.168.30.142 [View the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46QDU.png)) config is :

```
frontend storage_mysql_3306
  bind *:3306
  mode tcp
  use_backend storage_mysql_3306

backend storage_mysql_3306
  balance roundrobin
  mode tcp
  server 192_168_30_144_31695 192.168.30.144:31695
```

the mysql container is run at 192.168.30.144 [View the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uovDM.png), so what i want is :

```
server 192_168_30_144_3306 192.168.30.144:3306
```

so what should i do to slove it?
thanks!

Comment: In [link](http://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/ports.html)  i find __hostPort: A host port specifies a port on the host to bind to. When used with BRIDGE or USER mode networking, you specify a port mapping from a host port to a container port. In HOST networking, requested ports are host ports by default. Note that only host ports are made available to a task through environment variables.__

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer
http://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/host-port.html

**Mesos agents do NOT offer all ports**

Am I right?